# Piece of brass in air compressor tank -- problem or no?

Tags: repair, compressor

I recently inherited my first air compressor, which had a broken brass drainage valve. While attempting to remove it, I further broke the valve and lost a piece inside the compressor tank. I've tried tipping the tank around to roll the piece into the drainage hole, without success so far.

After initially giving up, I put a new valve on and ran the compressor up to ~50psi.

Is there any risk of running the compressor as is, with a loose piece of brass knocking around the tank? If not, what can I do to retrieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any risk of running the compressor as is, with a loose piece of brass knocking around the tank?

I dont think a loose piece of brass will be any issue.

> If not, what can I do to retrieve it?

Depending on the style you could perhaps de-pressurize the tank and remove the compressor or compressor discharge tube, giving you access to a larger port in the tank where you might be able to dump the loose piece. This can also lead to problems with leaks on the compressor discharge though... I think you are better off leaving it be.

Comment: If you're really worried about it or using expensive tools there are always in-line air filters to catch debris.